# Conic Ellipse problem

Tags: conic-sections

For an ellipse, $9x^2+4y^2=36$, find vertices and foci.

I would first standardised the equation in form $(x)^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2=1$ thus…………(i)

divide all sides by 36,I get:
$$(9x^2)/36+(4y^2)/36=36/36$$ which is equiv. to $x^2/4+y^2/9=36/36$

based on  $x^2/4+y^2/9=36/36$  we can rewrite this as:
$$x^2/2^2 +y^2/3^2 =1$$   which is in standard  $x^2/a^2 +y^2/b^2 =1$

we can even pluck out our values for a,b thus: a=2 and b=3

but by pythagoras,we know $c^2=a^2-b^2$ hence $c^2=2^2-3^2$

so in my case, $c^2=4-9= -5$ and $\therefore$  $c=√(-5)$

But I reckon the values of a,b can swap depending on  major axis since we can re-write standard equation as $$(x)^2/b^2 + y^2/b^2=1$$ which will bring a different value of $c^2$.

Questions: How do I make sure I get the correct value of $c^2$?
Question: How do ensure the ellipse is plotted on the correct major axis?

Comment: If I swap the values I would rewrite $x^2/b^2 + y^2/a^2=1$. Thus $x^2/3^2+y^2/2^2 = 1$. This will give $$c^2 = 3^2-2^2 = \sqrt(5)$$

Comment: First, 36/36 is just 1.

Comment: Correct. Sorry let me correct that in my answer.

Comment: To make sure that you found correct value of $c$, or any other "geometric" value, just check if it is real, not complex like $\sqrt {-5}$.

Comment: ^That's not correct, @Kaster. For an ellipse, $a$ **is the larger of a, b**, not the one that goes with the $x$.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 You can think of it that way too. For me algebraic representation of an ellipse as $x = a \cos \omega t, y = b \sin \omega t$ comes first, so $a$ is "whatever goes with the $x$", not a conic section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the ellipse $9x^2 + 4y^2 = 36$ ...

This is, as you have found, equivalent to $$\dfrac{x^2}{4} + \dfrac{y^2}{9} = 1$$

Now in an **ellipse**, the larger denominator corresponds with $a$.
*(Contrast this with a hyperbola, where the denominator of the positive variable term is $a^2$)*

So we find that $a = 3, b = 2$. The major axis is vertical, as the $a$ was under the $y^2$.

Therefore, the vertices are up and down $(a = 3)$ units from the center, which is the origin in this case.
The covertices are $(b = 2)$ units left and right of center.

$c = \sqrt5$, and the foci are $c$ units up and down from the center.

Comment: > in an ellipse, the larger denominator corresponds with a. Puzzling. I would put it this way: in the standard form $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$, it doesn't matter whether $a$ or $b$ is larger. You get an ellipse either way. The $a$ goes with the $x$ in the sense that the ellipse crosses the $x$-axis where $x = \pm a$. It's the formulae for foci and eccentricity that need some adjustment.

Comment: @bubba - hope it's not *too* puzzling, as the precalculus books that I've used for 10 years (Larson & Hostetler, pg 744) have exactly what I have written.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, I want to get it clear:If I get an equation $$x^2/2^2 +y^2/3^2 = 1$$: To know which value is $a$, I check the denominator is greater which in this case is $3^2$. To know which is the major axis, I check under which $a$ is the denominator, which is on $y^2$. The axis will be $x$. How do I know whether it is vertical or horizontal?